# Start activity in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I've decided to add more tablet-friendly UI to my app by creating a dual-pane layout using the new fragments API. But the problem is that lots of screens in my app are Activity subclasses. Manually converting them all to fragments is not an option because:
- There are nearly 50 activities.
- I'd like my app to be compatible with all versions of Android starting at 1.6
- And I'd like it to be as small as possible so using a compatibility library is not an option as it is too huge

Although I've found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249031/start-activity-in-a-fragment) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510165/loading-activity-in-fragment-code) whose answers are saying that it is impossible, I've done it almost successfully. Here is code of my custom Fragment:

```
public static class ActivityFragment extends Fragment{
    Intent intent;
    View view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(intent==null){
            Bundle a=getArguments();
            intent=a.getParcelable("intent");
        }
        LocalActivityManager am=((ActivityGroup)getActivity()).getLocalActivityManager();
        Window wnd=am.startActivity("intent"+intent.hashCode(), intent);
        if(view==null){
            view=wnd.getDecorView();
            view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(!((TabletMainActivity)getActivity()).tabs.containsValue(this)){
            ((ActivityGroup)getActivity()).getLocalActivityManager().destroyActivity("intent"+intent.hashCode(), true);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to work it must be used only in ActivityGroup.
Only problem is that in some activities with a ListView method onItemClick() does not get called after the activity is resumed, i.e. I click an item, another activity starts on top of current, but when I go back, items are no longer clickable.

Comment: You can't use fragments without the compatibility library and that adds only ~110kb to your apk.

Comment: I use them directly and enable only on Honeycomb.

Comment: That means you have to create ActivityFragments of Activities in addition for all parts that shall be used as Fragments - that increases your apk size as well and I don't see the benefit over using the support library.

Comment: No, as you can see from the code, I'm creating them dynamically passing an Intent as an argument.

Comment: You can't use a class that `extends Fragment` on a device that does not know what a Fragment is. Once you try to load that class into memory you get a ClassNotFoundException. The part where the intent is evaluated is way after that.

Comment: Yes I know, I use this code only on devices that support fragments natively, on others I start activities in full screen

Comment: Ok, I see what you are trying. I've seen it work but Idk what it is that causes your behavior. But it sounds like you may need to do focus management and event forwarding from your fragment to the activity window. E.g. TabHost does those sort of things (and the fragment api probably too). See [TabHost sourcecode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/TabHost.java#TabHost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution by comparing all ListView's fields' values before and after onResume. And solution to this problem is to call the `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` method on the list adapter.